# What is this PHP command?

Tags: php

```
$userauthorized = empty($_SESSION['userauthorized']) ? 0 : $_SESSION['userauthorized'];
```

I'm sure this is an elementary question and googling this is a nightmare.

What does the " ? 0 : " mean?

Comment: it's a shortcut for `if(){} else{}`. `?` stands for `if`, `:` for `else`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a [ternary operator](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) and it is essentially a short-hand `if()` statement.

You're basically saying:

```
if(empty($_SESSION['userauthorized'])) {
    $userauthorized =  0; 
} else {
    $userauthorized = $_SESSION['userauthorized'];
}
```